# separate function inside same class is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to decrease and increase the number and it works well. Here the question is, when i create a **separate function for my onTapDown function**, the number decrement is **not working**. Did i have made any mistake over here?  But when i place this inside my onTap function it works well just like the funtion in add incon.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Container1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Container1State createState() => _Container1State();
}

class _Container1State extends State<Container1> {
  int num = 20;
  Timer timer;
  void minusOnTapDown(int parameter) {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        parameter--;
        if (parameter <= 1) {
          timer.cancel();
          parameter = 1;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void plusOnTapDown(int parameter) {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        parameter--;
        if (parameter <= 0) {
          timer.cancel();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void cancelTimer(int parameter) {
    setState(() {
      timer.cancel();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '$num',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.0,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                  minusOnTapDown(num);
                },
                onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                  cancelTimer(num);
                },
                onTapCancel: () {
                  cancelTimer(num);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Icon(Icons.minimize),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 50.0,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                  print('Down');
                  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
                    setState(() {
                      num++;
                    });
                  });
                },
                onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                  setState(() {
                    print('Up');
                    timer.cancel();
                  });
                },
                onTapCancel: () {
                  print('Cancel');
                  timer.cancel();
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to add to the answers that have been provided. Although everything in dart is an object and hence primitives too, in practice, the behavior that it will exhibit is as if it was passed by value. (I'm not too sure why but I've seen a good explanation in Stack Overflow). Unless you are passing say an instance of the class, you will only change the copied value that ilves inside the function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error occurs because you are trying to decrease the parameter instead of the actual num. parameter-- wont reflect on num.

Call it like this:

```
onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
              minusOnTapDown();
            },
onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
              cancelTimer();
```

and make change in the function:

```
void minusOnTapDown() {
timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
  setState(() {
    num--;
    if (num<= 1) {
      timer.cancel();
      num= 1;
    }
  });
});
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: What can i do when i have more than one parameter like age and weight? In this case what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you create separate method you are passing a parameter named `parameter` and increasing or decreasing that. While the `num` variable which is the variable reflecting in the UI is totally unaffected. So in the separate method too, you need to increase or decrease the `num` variable directly. And there is no need to pass the `parameter`.

```
  void minusOnTapDown() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        num--;
        if (num <= 1) {
          timer.cancel();
          num = 1;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

And call it in the `onTapDown` callback.

```
onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                  minusOnTapDown();
                },
```

Comment: What can i do when i have more than one parameter like age and weight? In this case what should i do?

Comment: You can pass the case String as a parameter in the method. And based on whether it is age, weight etc.. switch cases inside the method and increase/decrease the corresponding variable accordingly.

Comment: @Arud sorry, I did not understand what you mean. "I should it...." ??